# Do ROS srv open and close nodes?

Tags: rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

Not sure if it's important information for this question but I am using ROS indigo.

Let me give you the back story. I have two nodes. Lets call them Node1 and Node2. Node1 publishes messages to Node2. But Node2 does not want a continues stream of data. So the logical thing is to make Node1 use a srv so Node2 can request the data when ever it needs it. Here is where I am skeptical.

When ever I run Node1 (using rosrun) it needs about 2.5 seconds to start streaming data. After it starts, it will send data every 0.5 sec.

If I use srv on Node1, will it need the 2.5 sec it need to start (so every time Node2 request something Node1 will startup, answer and close down) or will it be able to answer every 0.5 sec (so Node1 does not close down but is in a "idle" state)  like it does now that it is continuously sending data?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218193/do-ros-srv-open-and-close-nodes?/) by [Metalzero2](https://answers.ros.org/users/20078/metalzero2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 293 on 2015-09-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a reason why you don't just try?

If Node1 is already running, it will be able to answer the service-request immediately.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2015-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Metalzero2](https://answers.ros.org/users/20078/metalzero2/) on 2015-09-24**:
Because I am not experienced with rossrv yet and it will take me many hours to change it from rosmsg. I just wanted to be sure that it will not need the initialization time (the 2.5 sec). Thanks very mush for your help :)